# Unable to apply Git Tag in Azure pipeline cloud build. Works on local agent though

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, git-tag, azure-pipelines-yaml

Despite following the [Microsoft instructions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) on how to give a YAML pipeline the ability to run Git commands in a script, I can't seem to make mine properly apply a Git tag to the repo when I build in the cloud.  It works on the local hosted agent though.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

I keep getting this error:

```
2020-07-28T03:04:25.7818359Z + git push origin  v1.0.6253
2020-07-28T03:04:25.7818711Z + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-07-28T03:04:25.7821133Z     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (To https://dev....ftware/_git/Sdk:String) [], RemoteException
2020-07-28T03:04:25.7822040Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
2020-07-28T03:04:25.7822281Z  
2020-07-28T03:04:25.9298244Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

My YAML step looks like this:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Tag the build with v$(fullVersion)'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      cd $(sdkFolder)
      git config user.email "me@mycompany.com"
      git config user.name "Build Script"
      git tag -a v$(fullVersion) -m "Nightly Build"
      git push origin v$(fullVersion)
```

(Note: I used my actual name and address in the actual script)

When I say I "followed the Microsoft instructions", I mean I gave my repo's "Project Collection Build Service" user the rights to do the following (it already had the other rights)

```
Contribute
Create branch
Create tag
```

Here's what that user's permissions look like:

[image]

And I was careful to apply `persistCredentials: true` to the repo checkout

```
steps:
- checkout: git://Software/Sdk
  persistCredentials: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation is succeeded, this is not a "real" error, it's because `git push` is sending output to stderr, not stdout so PowerShell thinks it's an error.

How to prevent it?

There are several options but the shortest it's just to add `--porcelain` to the `git push`:

```
git push origin v$(fullVersion) --porcelain
```

Comment: Wow!  That's it exactly.  The tags are right there in my online repo.  It's just that when I saw the error message, I never even thought to check for them.   That's brilliant.  Thank you.  How on Earth did you know that?

Comment: @Joe I faced such errors in the past with git + PowerShell (in clone, push, etc.) so I made some research then...